# Can't prevent default on "mousewheel" event after I load page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I used ajax to load content from external file (called menu.html). Now I have my menu and when I click on a tag with href to another page which I load with AJAX call where I had my previous content (menu page loaded with ajax).

Here is git repository to this project is: https://github.com/szymonhernik/ArtHer_ajax

```
//----------- AJAX calls on menu clicks --------------//

(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var $content,
      $section;

  function loadMenuLink(url) {
        $.ajax(url,{ dataType: "text" })
        .then(function(contents){
            $content.html(contents);
        });
  }

  function stopScroll() {
    $section.on('mousewheel', function() {
      //do nothing-> dont load menu.html
    });
  }

  function pageClicked(evt) {

      evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      evt.preventDefault();

      var url = $(this).attr("href");
      loadMenuLink(url);
      stopScroll();
  }


  function bindings () {
    $(document).on("click", "#menu a", pageClicked);
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
     $content = $('.content');
     $section = $('section');

     bindings();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

I have got this small module- firstly to take the url from a tag's href using pageClicked function and then function loadMenuLink when I pass this url.

This is my html code for this page (menu page):

```
<div id="menu" class="menu animated fadeIn" rel="js-menu">
  <div class="menu-bar animated fadeInUp">

    <a href="about.html" rel="js-about"><p>O nas</p></a><span>/</span>
    <a href="projects.html" rel="js-projects"><p>Projekty</p></a><span>/</span>
    <a href="clients.html" rel="js-clients"><p>Nasi klienci</p></a><span>/</span>
    <a href="contact.html" rel="js-contact"><p>Kontakt</p></a>

 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that after I load menu.html I can't prevent default 'mousewheel' event when I scroll-> I want to do nothing on scroll after I load menu.html.

I will upload my first ajax function, maybe you can find a problem there.

```
(function($) {
 "use strict";

 var $section,
     $elements,
     $content,
     $arrow,
     $label;

 function goToMenu (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   e.preventDefault();

   if(e.deltaY /120 > 0) {
     $('.menu').fadeOut(500, function () { $(this).remove();});
     $elements.removeClass("animated fadeOut not-active");
     $elements.addClass("animated fadeIn");
   }
   else if (e.deltaY /120 < 0) {
     $.ajax('menu.html',{ dataType: "text" })
       .then(function(contents){
          $content.html(contents);
          $elements.addClass("animated fadeOut not-active");
     });
    }
   }

   function arrowToMenu (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax('menu.html',{ dataType: "text" })
       .then(function(contents){
         $content.html(contents);
         $elements.addClass("animated fadeOut not-active");
       });
     }


 function bindings () {
   $section.on('mousewheel', goToMenu);
   $arrow.on('click', arrowToMenu);
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $elements = $('.elements');
    $section = $('section');
    $content = $('.content');
    $label = $('.label');
    $arrow = $('.arrow');

    bindings();
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is git repository to this project is: https://github.com/szymonhernik/ArtHer_ajax

Hope that anyone can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Any alerts in the console? You may want to add `console.log(e)` to see what event is being passed.

Comment: Hello, I don't have any alerts in the console. When I console.log(e) after loading page with AJAX I don't get any consoled values although when I pass console.log(e) in the function when scrolling event was firstly declared I get consolled normal mousescroll event...

Comment: so the `type` is `mousescroll`? Not `mousewheel`? If that is the case, maybe you should adjust you `.on()` to include both.

Comment: Excuse me- I meant mousewheel. I want this make this event unavailable after I load sth with AJAX.

Comment: What is: `$section = $('section');`? are you selecting all `<section>` elements, a class, or an id?

Comment: Oh, this is my div, that takes most of the window. This is the link to the html code: https://github.com/szymonhernik/ArtHer_ajax/blob/master/_site/index.html

Comment: Which part is scrolling? The `div.home-sections` or the `section`?

Comment: May also consider `return false;` in your function.

Comment: Neither of these, actually nothing is scrolling. You have a rectangle in the center of page (this is div with class content) where on mousewhell I upload a menu with ajax and then when I click on a tag i load instead new page (for example contact.html).

Comment: Where should I put return false? I've tried to return false or pass null but neither of these work

Comment: At the end of `goToMenu()`. Testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2f46ao3v/

Comment: Also, it looks like you can check: `e.isDefaultPrevented()` will return false or true if `e.preventDefault()` has been run. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2f46ao3v/2/

Comment: Id didn't help. Still after loading sth with ajax I have behaviour defined with first mousewheel event.

Comment: It looks like I can't rewrite first behaviour...

Comment: Did you try `.unbind()` and then bind?

Comment: @Twisty I finally did this. Following your advice, I added unbind method but firstly I had to rebuild my modules a little bit so I could return function which was responsible for mousewheel functionality and then unbind this in the second module. Later on, I will add EventEmmiter but for now, it's working. I will upload my updated git repo if anyone in the future has the same problem. This is a link to the repaired js functionality (https://github.com/szymonhernik/ArtHer_ajax/blob/8352bc9c35f641d9eeaad4faa3e68edc981ed296/_site/assets/js/functions.js)

Comment: @Twisty thank you for all your assistance